# Nuget "already has a reference to"

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Tests.Functional is selected from the `Default project:` drop down.

```
PM> install-package nunit
'NUnit 2.6.0.12054' already installed.
Tests.Functional already has a reference to 'NUnit 2.6.0.12054'.
```

Yet Nunit does not show up in References for Tests.Functional in the Solution Explorer. Tried reloading VS.Net (2010) and updating Nuget.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Strange. Can you try  reinstalling the package : "uninstall-package nunit" then 
"install-package nunit" ?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue (with another package) but I can't uninstall the package nor does it get listed with `Get-Package`, however trying to reinstall the package yields `[myProject] already contains a reference to [myPackage]`.

Answer (score 14):

When running the solution under TFS, make sure the $(SolutionDir)\Packages\repositories.config file is checked out for edit.

Try the following:

```
Uninstall-Package NUnit -Force
```

Verify the Tests.Functional.csproj file (using notepad) no longer has any Reference to NUnit (if it still does, manually delete them, the project file probably got corrupted somehow).

Then run the following commandl:

```
Install-Package NUnit
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to a similar issue trying to download the xunit framework when looking at the Entity Framework code. I worked around this by selecting a project to install to xunit to that didn't have the reference already, then just went in to manage and removed the reference to the project that didn't actually need it.

It appears that when a project references an assembly it doesn't have, nuget will see the reference and think that it doesn't need the assembly, even though it does. Simply adding the assembly to another project through nuget solves the issue. Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the Package Manager Console:

```
Uninstall-Package NUnit -Force
```

Then, go into your project directory and and manually remove NUnit references from your packages.config & .csproject files if any.

Now you can simply Install using:

```
Install-Package NUnit
```